# How do you specify file upload directory for express within sails?

Tags: file-upload, express, sails.js

I'm uploading a file from a browser `<input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile"` using sails. I need to place it in other than the default express location. I'd use the following code in naked Express:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: uploadFolder }))
```

For sails I wrote code along the lines of [this relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18215906/add-express-middleware-for-param-validations/18292517)

First, I tried SkyTecLabs' answer. policies/configfileupload.js contains

```
'use strict';
var sailsExpress = require('../../node_modules/sails/node_modules/express'),
    path = require('path');
console.log('.. initializing policies/configFileUpload');

module.exports = function configFileUpload (req, res, next) {
  var uploadFolder = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../public/uploads');
  console.log('.. in policies/configfileupload.js. uploadFolder=', uploadFolder);
  console.log('typeofs are=',typeof req, typeof res, typeof next, typeof sailsExpress);
  sailsExpress.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: uploadFolder });
  next();
};
```

config/policies.js contains

```
'SchedController' : {
  'uploadsubmit': 'configfileupload'
}
```

Express continues to upload the file to the default directory. Typeof req, res, next, sailsexpress are: object, object, function, function so the signature looks OK. (I tried returning the function configFileUpload just in case, but the controller was never called.)

Then I tried mikemcneil's suggestion. config/express.js

```
'use strict';
var sailsExpress = require('../node_modules/sails/node_modules/express'),
    path = require('path');

module.exports.express = {
  customMiddleware: function (app) {
    var uploadFolder = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../public/uploads');
    console.log('.. in config/express.js. uploadFolder=', uploadFolder);
    console.log('typeof sailsExpress=', typeof sailsExpress, 'typeof app=', typeof app);
    app.use(sailsExpress.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: uploadFolder  }));
  }
};
```

and the upload was still placed in the default directory. The typeofs sailsexpress and app are both function.

If the above code is correct for including express middleware in sails, then perhaps this middleware is performed only after express' formidable dependency parses the data and uploads the file.

I don't know in this case of any place in sails where I can place express configuration options such as bodyParser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> #### Warning: Before you release your app...
>
> If you're expecting lots of file uploads, and especially big ones, you need to reconsider your strategy before deploying into production.  You can replace the bodyParser middleware manually by [replacing](https://github.com/mikermcneil/stream-debug/blob/master/examples/sails/config/express.js#L3) `sails.config.express.bodyParser`.

The default bodyParser in Express/Connect (and Sails, as of v0.9.x) uses a tmp directory to buffer files (similar to what you'd see in PHP).  To get uploaded files somewhere else, you'll need to move them.  Check out http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads for more on how to do that.

There is another option you might check out, depending on how adventurous you are.  As I have time, I've been working on an alternative default bodyParser that can be used with Sails or Express.  It defers to the underlying library for param/JSON parsing, but uses formidable's raw onPart events to allow streaming uploads without writing the entire file to disk.  More on that:

- Example repo: https://github.com/mikermcneil/stream-debug
- Discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sailsjs/525fK7pgK8U/bduPudCSLUgJ
- Source: https://github.com/mikermcneil/file-parser