# Sails 0.10.5 compress middleware and serving gzipped assets

Tags: express, gzip, sails.js

In sails 0.10.5 express compression is supposed to be in the middleware for production mode by default according to the issues on github, but none of the response headers have the appropriate Content-Encoding to suggest that they have been gzipped.  Furthermore, the sizes of the assets all match the uncompressed assets.

After searching for any other issues related to this, I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743019/how-to-gzip-javascript-and-css-assets-in-sails-js) which was theoretically the opposite of my problem: he had the gzipped files in place and needed the middleware and I have the middleware (supposedly by default) but no files. His problem was (apparently) solved by adding the middleware config, which was required for compression before 0.10.5.  So, I npm installed grunt-contrib-compress and set up the config file.  Now, I have the gzipped files being produced successfully, but they're not being served.  I tried manually requesting the gzipped version of the asset by injecting it in sails-linker instead of the regular js, but the Content-Type on the response header was 'application/octect-stream'.

Has anyone successfully served gzipped static assets from a sails app?  Am I doing anything obviously incorrectly?  Even an outline of the general process would be appreciated.